# Keep getting WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when running automation in jenkins

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation

When my test script tries to open the URL in the chrome browser on a remote machine(using jenkins), i get an error WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The URL is a company site and i have tried using proxies but does not help.

It was able to open google.com.

Below is the docker command im running in the pipeline script:

```
sh 'docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" --env HTTP_PROXY="http://sub.proxy.company.com:1234" --env HTTPS_PROXY="http://sub.proxy.company.com:1234" --env NO_PROXY="*.company.com,localhost,127.0.0.1" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.17.0-20240123'
```

I've tried with proxies and without, but still no luck.